# Counting Rows Based on Exist Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, count, aggregate-functions

I have researched many Stackoverflow questions that demonstrate how to add conditions to the COUNT statement using a CASE statement but I can't find an example of how to do what I need to.  Let's assume I have the following tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [Project](
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [ProjectTask](
    [ProjectTaskId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProjectId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [TaskName] [nvarchar](100) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [ProjectTaskOwner](
    [ProjectTaskId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UserId] [int] NOT NULL
 )
GO

CREATE TABLE [ProjectTaskEntity](
    [ProjectTaskId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [EntityId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [AssignedUserId] [int]
 )
GO

INSERT Project (ProjectId, ProjectName) VALUES (1, 'Test Project')
INSERT ProjectTask (ProjectTaskId, ProjectId, TaskName) VALUES(1, 1, 'Task1')
INSERT ProjectTask (ProjectTaskId, ProjectId, TaskName) VALUES(2, 1, 'Task2')
INSERT ProjectTaskOwner (ProjectTaskId, UserId) VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT ProjectTaskOwner (ProjectTaskId, UserId) VALUES (1, 2)
INSERT ProjectTaskOwner (ProjectTaskId, UserId) VALUES (1, 3)
INSERT ProjectTaskEntity (ProjectTaskId, EntityId, AssignedUserId) VALUES (1, 1, 1)
INSERT ProjectTaskEntity (ProjectTaskId, EntityId, AssignedUserId) VALUES (1, 2, 2)
INSERT ProjectTaskEntity (ProjectTaskId, EntityId, AssignedUserId) VALUES (1, 3, 3)
INSERT ProjectTaskEntity (ProjectTaskId, EntityId, AssignedUserId) VALUES (1, 4, 256)
```

What I want to do is get for each Project Task the count of entities that are assigned to me and assigned to other task owners.  So for the test data above, given a user id of 1 and a project id of 1 I expect:

```
| TaskId | AssignedToMe | AssignedToOthers |
|   1    |      1       |       2          |
|   2    |      0       |       0          |
```

So here is what I have so far:

```
DECLARE @userId INT = 1   
SELECT 
    pt.ProjectId,
    pt.ProjectTaskId,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId = @userId THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AssignedTo
FROM ProjectTask pt
INNER JOIN Project p
    ON p.ProjectId = pt.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN ProjectTaskEntity pte
    ON pte.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId
WHERE p.ProjectId = 1
GROUP BY pt.ProjectId,  pt.ProjectTaskId
```

Assigned to me was easy.  The problem is I'm not sure how to do others because others isn't just anyone not me.  It is anyone not in the ProjectTaskOwner table for this task.  Anyone have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the actual query that solved my problem.  There are several posts that helped me find this so thanks to everyone for your answers:

```
DECLARE @userId INT = 1   
SELECT 
    pt.ProjectId,
    pt.ProjectTaskId,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId = @userId THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AssignedTo,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN eao.OtherUser IS NULL THEN NULL ELSE 1 END) AS AssignedToOther
FROM ProjectTask pt
LEFT JOIN ProjectTaskEntity pte
    ON pte.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT sPto.ProjectTaskId, sPto.UserId as OtherUser
    FROM ProjectTaskOwner sPto
    WHERE sPto.UserId <> @userId
) eao
    ON  pt.ProjectTaskId = eao.ProjectTaskId AND pte.AssignedUserId = eao.OtherUser
WHERE pt.ProjectId = 1
GROUP BY pt.ProjectId,  pt.ProjectTaskId
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't see why you need to project table for this.  I would write this as:

```
SELECT pt.ProjectId, pt.ProjectTaskId,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId = @userId THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AssignedToMe,
       SUM(CASE WHEN pto.UserId IS NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS AssignedToOthers
FROM ProjectTask pt LEFT JOIN
     ProjectTaskEntity pte
     ON pte.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId LEFT JOIN
     ProjectTaskOwner pto
     ON pto.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId AND
        pto.UserId = pte.AssignedUserId
WHERE pt.ProjectId = 1
GROUP BY pt.ProjectId, pt.ProjectTaskId;
```

I replaced the `COUNT()` with `SUM()`.  As a matter of preference, I prefer `SUM()` in this situation.

Comment: You query returns `AssignedToOthers`=1 for Task 2. See this [**fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58f1e4/11).

Comment: @RagingBull . . . The OP explains the conditions in two different paragraphs -- and the explanations are a bit different.  I fixed the answer for the explanation in the final paragraph.

Comment: @GordonLinoff...Sorry about the extra join..my actual case is more complicated and I forgot to remove that join.  Your solution is close but produces AssignedToOthers = 1 for Task2 and only 1 for Task1.  The answer is 
Task 1 - AssignedToMe = 1 Assigned To Others = 2
Task 2 - AssignedToMe = 0 Assigned To Others = 0

Answer (score 0):

It's as simple as doing the opposite

```
DECLARE @userId INT = 1   
SELECT 
    pt.ProjectId,
    pt.ProjectTaskId,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId = @userId THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AssignedToMe,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId = @userId THEN null ELSE 0 END) AS AssignedToOthers

FROM ProjectTask pt
INNER JOIN Project p
    ON p.ProjectId = pt.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN ProjectTaskEntity pte
    ON pte.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId
WHERE p.ProjectId = 1
GROUP BY pt.ProjectId,  pt.ProjectTaskId
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment but you missed the point about it NOT being just users other than me but other users that are also assigned to this task as owners.

Answer (score 0):

Use `SUM` instead of `COUNT`:

```
DECLARE @userId INT = 1   
SELECT pt.ProjectTaskId,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId = @userId THEN 1 END),0) AS AssignedToMe,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId <> @userId THEN 1 END),0) AS AssignedToOthers
FROM ProjectTask pt
INNER JOIN Project p ON p.ProjectId = pt.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN ProjectTaskEntity pte ON pte.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId
WHERE p.ProjectId = 1
GROUP BY  pt.ProjectTaskId
```

With the data you have provided, it will result:

```
ProjectTaskId   AssignedToMe    AssignedToOthers
1               1               3
2               0               0
```

See result in [**SQL Fiddle**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58f1e4/15).

Comment: Thanks for your comment but you missed the point about it NOT being just users other than me but other users that are also assigned to this task as owners.

Answer (score 0):

I think this solves the problem. 
You'll be counting others as not you and anyone not in the ProjectTaskOwner table for this task.

```
DECLARE @userId INT = 1   
SELECT 
    pt.ProjectId,
    pt.ProjectTaskId,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId = @userId THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AssignedTo,
    COUNT(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId != @userId AND pte.AssignedUserId != pto.UserId THEN 1 ELSE NULL END) AS AssignedTo
FROM ProjectTask pt
INNER JOIN Project p
    ON p.ProjectId = pt.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN ProjectTaskEntity pte
    ON pte.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId
LEFT JOIN ProjectTaskOwner pto
    on pto.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId
WHERE p.ProjectId = 1
GROUP BY pt.ProjectId,  pt.ProjectTaskId
```

Comment: Because of the extra join it artificially inflates the numbers.  For example, your query gives 3 assigned to me and 7 assigned to others.  The result should be 1 assigned to me and 2 to others.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @userId INT = 1   
SELECT 
    pt.ProjectId,
    pt.ProjectTaskId,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId = @userId THEN 1 END),0) AS AssignedToMe,
    ISNULL(SUM(CASE WHEN pte.AssignedUserId <> @userId THEN 1 END),0) AS AssignedToOthers
FROM ProjectTask pt
INNER JOIN Project p
    ON p.ProjectId = pt.ProjectId
LEFT JOIN ProjectTaskOwner pto
    ON pto.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId
LEFT JOIN ProjectTaskEntity pte
    ON pte.ProjectTaskId = pt.ProjectTaskId and
    pte.AssignedUserId = pto.UserId
WHERE p.ProjectId = 1
GROUP BY pt.ProjectId,  pt.ProjectTaskId
```

http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/58f1e4/28

Comment: Yes this is the answer.  Thanks!